# Why Can I Return A List Of A Type Not Specified By My List<T> Return Type?

Tags: java, generics

Given the following classes...

---

```
package whoop.deduper;

/**
 * @author deduper
 *
 */
public class Foo {

}
```

---

```
package whoop.deduper;


import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author deduper
 *
 */
public class FuBar {

    public int fuBar( ){

        Bar bar = new Bar();

        List<Foo> foos = bar.foos();

        int baz = 0;

        for ( Iterator iterator = foos.iterator( ); iterator.hasNext( ); ) {

            BigDecimal foo = (BigDecimal) iterator.next( );

            baz = foo.intValue( );

            return baz;

        }

        return baz;     

    }

}
```

---

```
package whoop.deduper;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author deduper
 *
 */
public class Bar {

    public <T extends Foo> List<T> foos( ) {

        List sketchy = new ArrayList();

        sketchy.add( BigDecimal.TEN );

        return sketchy;
    }

}
```

---

```
package whoop.deduper;

import static java.lang.System.out;

/**
 * @author deduper
 *
 */
public class EffedUp {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main( String[ ] args ) {

        int effedUp = new FuBar().fuBar( );

        out.println(effedUp + " — But it works!");

    }

}
```

---

...why does that even work? I mean, I would have expected a ClassCastException or something somewhere in there! Why isn't there?

Please can somebody point me to a clearly written explanation that documents what's going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can because of this raw type `List sketchy = new ArrayList();`. Also your IDE should warn you about that return in `Bar#foos`.

Answer (score 1):

Having a variable of type `List<Foo>` doesn't guarantee that you actually have a list of Foos. You will only make sure when you try to pull Foos out, which you are not, your Iterator is not an `Iterator<Foo>` and you are not casting to `Foo` anywhere. If you let the compiler to do the casting for you, then it will break as expected.

```
 List<Foo> foos = bar.foos();

  int baz = 0;

  for (Foo foo : foos) {
     System.out.println(foo); // ClassCastException
  }
```

If you go with the "normal" route as shown above, the complier will get itself an iterator and cast every element to `Foo`, and hence the above code would fail if the list is not empty.

Your code demonstrates how bad [raw-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it?rq=1) are and why one should always avoid them.

Answer (score -1):

```
  List l = new ArrayList();
  List<Integer> ints = l;
```

When you make the assignment, you will tell Java to put the address of `l` in `ints` and nothing more. This happens at runtime when generics are erased from the code.

Generics are used by the compiler at compile time when the compiler tries to identify possible errors related to types. It doesn't crash at compile time because he doesn't know what values are stored inside the list because none were specified. It will crash at runtime with `ClassCastException` when the list will contain unexpected elements (because only at runtime you will have the objects).

I cannot figure out the reason why they allowed this to happen at compile time. I would've expected a compile error if the compiler would've encountered something like this. Instead of error, you will get warnings.

When you make the assignment you will just say `I give you a list, doesn't matter what it has inside, you just store it`.

As an advice, always specify the type of a list. In your case `List<T>`. Keep this in mind as long as you don't need to have a list with many object types which in my experience is kind of rare.